# error while installing active admin gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I am trying to install the latest version of activeadmin gem to my rails app. I followed the documentation http://activeadmin.info/documentation.html but I got this error when I run rake db:migrate.

```
rake aborted!
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require': no such file to load -- InheritedResources

Tasks: TOP => db:migrate => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I installed InheritedResources

```
gem install InheritedResources
```

this is my gem file

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.3'

#working with capastrano 
# gem 'mysql2', '< 0.3'

#upgraded for local 
gem 'mysql2', "~> 0.3.11"

group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
  gem 'compass-rails'
  # gem 'haml', '3.1.4'
  # gem 'haml-rails'
end


gem 'activeadmin'
gem "meta_search",    '>= 1.1.0.pre'
gem 'inherited_resources'

#Media managment
gem 'ruby_parser'
gem 'hpricot'
group :development do 
    ##gem 'annotate', :git => 'git://github.com/ctran/annotate_models.git' 
end

group :test do 
end

group :production do 
end

# deployment 
gem 'capistrano'
```

this is my gem env

```
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.3.6
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.8.7 (2010-01-10 patchlevel 249) [universal-darwin11.0]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - universal-darwin-11
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8
     - /Users/aaalsubaie/.gem/ruby/1.8
     - /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :benchmark => false
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
     - "gem" => "--no-ri --no-rdoc"
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - http://rubygems.org/
```

Comment: have you tried bundle install?

Comment: yes i did. I installed the gem, added it to the gemfile and bundle it with no errors. when I try to migrate the db the error above appear.

Comment: just to be sure, you did this as well ? rails generate active_admin:install

Comment: I did follow the whole documentation in the activeadmin website.